# Setup help for new user on 14.04 LTS required

Tags: 14.04, lts

Can I use my existing Windows partitions to install Ubuntu?
I don't want to loose files and I also don't want to change the partitions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can install Ubuntu using wubi.exe (located in your downloaded iso image) under Windows. It will use the windows partition to store a virtual file system and it will get a boot entry, so you can start it. But it will still be installed under Windows like any other software. That means, if you screw Windows, Ubuntu has a problem too. And you can remove it again through the Windows Software Settings like normal programs.

Answer (score 0):

Simply install Ubuntu following this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu).

At step **Installation Type** select **Install Ubuntu alongside Windows**.

This way partitioning will be done automatically by the Ubuntu installer and none are your Windows data/files will be lost.

---

#### Before doing anything : Make sure you do a backup !

> The installer's behavior is not always predictable. Sometimes it
> considers an existing partition to be worth keeping, sometimes not.
> And this option will only be available, if there is either
> unpartitioned space on the disk, or there are other partitions besides
> the Windows system partition (this may also accidentally be your data
> partition!), which then will probably get overwritten. - [Byte Commander](https://askubuntu.com/users/367990/byte-commander)

Comment: **Make sure you do a backup before this!** The installer's behaviour is not always predictable. Sometimes it considers an existing partition to be worth keeping, sometimes not. And this option will only be available, if there is either unpartitioned space on the disk, or there are other partitions besides the Windows system partition (this may also accidentally be your data partition!), which then will probably get overwritten.